# Trapping AngularJS / Angular-ui-routing HTTP errors in order to take action

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've developed an AngularJS application (SPA) using Angular 1.3.14.

I've set up my routing with Angular-ui-router (0.2.15).

The SPA is essentially divided into two sections; (1) the 'site' which is everything that is public; and (2) the 'app' which requires a valid `SessionID` in a header. Otherwise, it throws an HTTP 401.

Everything works relatively well and as expected. That is as long as I have a valid SessionID. If my SessionID has expired (or provide none), the HTTP 401 is returned (as required).

Since I'm using Angular-ui-routing with the `templateUrl` and `controller` options, all the pages (views) are auto-magically loaded.

So I'm not too sure where/how I would intercept the HTTP 401 in order to appropriately redirect to the **Sign In** page. Right now they are silently ignored and the pages (views) are not loaded.

I would like to trap the HTTP 401 errors (or at least one of them) and provide a valid message to the user (ie: "session expired" or "login required" or something after having redirected to the Sign In page.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update: 2018.10.04 21:44**

I found the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.log("State change error:");
    console.log(" > Event      : ", event);
    console.log(" > toState    : ", toState);
    console.log(" > toParams   : ", toParams);
    console.log(" > fromState  : ", fromState);
    console.log(" > fromParams : ", fromParams);
    console.log(" > error      : ", error);
    //event.preventDefault();
});
```

Interestingly, the `error` parameter contains the following:

```
  > error :  {data: {…}, status: 401, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: ""}
```

Which allows me to do this:

```
if (error.data.success === false) {
  console.log("Redirecting to 'Sign-in' page...");
  $state.go('sign-in');
}
```

The only issue remaining is that I have many views for the state and although I can trap the error and redirect, all the other views are still sent to the server and fail. Is this because they are all sent in parallel? Will keep digging!

Comment: You want to setup and use an `Interceptor`.  Used them to monitor responses from `$http`, and take the appropriate action.  The [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) have an example

Comment: Thanks @BrendanGreen, I'll take a look at it.